# Creating swipeable intro in android

Tags: android, view, swipe, manual

I'm looking for a a tutorial or a start for creating swipeable intros like this image for introducing and helping users in using the app, I know it is based on android swipeable views but all the links I found had tabs, and since these kinds of intros are very popular I though maybe there is a better and more forward way to do it.
[image]
Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use : Android-ViewPagerIndicator lib(https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

Comment: Thanks it seems to be exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `ViewPager` and a library called `ViewPagerIndicator` for the small circle at the bottom.